# парсинг сайта,нужно чтобы скрипт выдавал количество зараженных ,но он ничего не выдает,в чем ошибка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def parse():
    url = 'https://coronavirus-monitor.ru/statistika/'
    HEADERS = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 YaBrowser/20.3.2.242 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36'

    }       

    response = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.findAll('div', class_ = 'cell')
    print(items)
    comps = []

    for item in items:
        comps.append({
            'blackk': item.find('span', class_ = 'black').get_text(strip = True)

        })

        for comp in comps:
            print(comp['title'])    
parse()
input()
```

Comment: @gil9red мне на `items = soup.findAll('span', class_ = 'black')`  выдало `[<span class="black">1609946</span>, <span class="black">358518</span>, <span class="black">95805</span>]` дальше мне разбираться лень

Comment: @splash58, сейчас попробовал и у меня это ничего не нашло. А посмотрев в код страницы увидел, что там значения через js заполняются

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел на ту страницу и там заполнение значения таблицы статистики было через [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), поэтому понадобилось использовать библиотеку с js-движком.

С парсингом помог [requests-html](https://github.com/psf/requests-html). При первом запуске для **render()** тот установит [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) *или его аналог*.

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/be8577af8083e0c34f4457f67b02758a36427b2b/requests_html__examples/coronavirus_monitor_ru__statistika.py#L11)

```
# pip install requests-html
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
rs = session.get('https://coronavirus-monitor.ru/statistika/')
rs.html.render()  # Без этого не будет выполнения js кода

for row in rs.html.find('#statistics .total-table-row'):
    name = row.find('.name', first=True).text.rstrip(':')
    value = row.find('.value', first=True).text

    print(name, value)

# Зараженных 1635879
# Тяжелобольных 1097
# На подозрении 1141
# Смертей 99420
# Вылеченных 368052
```